# Unable to connect to Redis Cluster from inside Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, redis, redis-cluster

I have a Node app using this [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) javascript client library. My problem is that I am unable to connect this app, which is also dockerized, to my Redis Cluster(at ports 7000 to 7005) and its container. Here's my setup and the results:

I clone this [Docker-redis-cluster](https://github.com/Grokzen/docker-redis-cluster) repo and follow the instructions to build the image from the `Dockerfile`.

```
$ docker build -t gsccheng/redis-cluster .
```

Before building however, my only change was to set my own version which I have changed to

```
ARG redis_version=3.2.1
```

Following the instructions I run

```
docker run -i -t -p 7000:7000 -p 7001:7001 -p 7002:7002 -p 7003:7003 -p 7004:7004 -p 7005:7005 -p 7006:7006 -p 7007:7007 gsccheng/redis-cluster
```

## **GREAT SO FAR...**

Other than a few warnings like: `WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.`, so far so good. Why?:

1. Here's a screenshot of the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS00p.jpg).
2. I can enter the CLI using `redis-cli -c -p 7000`
3. With `docker inspect [container id]` I see it has a NetworkSettings > IPAddress of 172.17.0.2 and in NetworkSettings > Ports I see

   ```
   "Ports": {
               "6379/tcp": null,
               "7000/tcp": [
                   {
                       "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                       "HostPort": "7000"
                   }
               ],
               ...
            }
   ```

Next, I stop and delete all the containers. I navigate to the root of my web app where I have a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` which is here:

### **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
        - redis
  redis:
    image: gsccheng/redis-cluster
    ports:
      - '7000:7000'
      - '7001:7001'
      - '7002:7002'
      - '7003:7003'
      - '7004:7004'
      - '7005:7005'
```

### **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:4.4.7

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

### **connect.js**

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';
console.log('I am totally in here');

// The commented out host options shows the many different configurations I tried too.
const node = [{
            // Just need to connect to at least one of the startup nodes in the cluster. Redis will find the rest of the nodes in the cluster. All nodes only have a single db of 0 and SELECT is disabled.
            port: 7000,
            // host: '0.0.0.0'
            // host: '127.0.0.1'
            // host: '172.18.0.4'
            host: 'redis'
            // host: 'gsccheng/redis-cluster'
        }, {
            port: 7001,
            // host: '0.0.0.0'
            // host: '127.0.0.1'
            // host: '172.18.0.4'
            host: 'redis'
            // host: 'gsccheng/redis-cluster'
        }]

client = new Redis.Cluster(node, {});
...
```

I then run

```
$ docker-compose build
```

and

```
$ docker-compose up
```

The output is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/gsccheng/eec657e22c5dba109dc518654a8600ce). I deleted some irrelevant lines from there (indicated by a "...") for this example.

If it makes a difference, my app was built from this React-redux [boilerplate](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example), but it didn't include Redis.

## **Sanity Check**

1. With `docker-compose up` running and the errors continuously logging as you see in the gist, I can still connect to the cluster from outside of the container when I execute:

   ```
   $ redis-cli -c -p 7000
   ```
2. `$ docker ps` shows this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjyiV.jpg).
3. `$ docker exec 4b3ec3e53e32 ps aux | grep redis` shows this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqvBf.jpg).
4. Here's the full [output](https://gist.github.com/gsccheng/be6fb2bc8d4dcc71b630c9f81beccfe0) from `$ docker inspect 4b3ec3e53e32` again of the redis container. Notice the `"IPAddress": ""` under `NetworkSettings`...

**Further questions**

5. ...Why is that blank now? Is that why my Redis client couldn't connect to the cluster?
6. What's the difference between that ip and the `"HostIp": "0.0.0.0",`? The `0.0.0.0` was bound in the `redis.conf` configurations and I think it means that the server would only listen to requests from that address. Does that mean the IP listed there must match the ip of my other `ctn_web_1` container?
7. We also saw from the output of `docker-compose up` that the Redis servers are up at `172.18.0.2`. I've noticed that this also changed a lot from instance to instance (e.g. `172.18.0.4`, `172.18.0.3`) of me running `docker-compose`. Why? Is it because I didn't fully delete the containers yet before running again? However, I shouldn't be using this ip address in my `connect.js` code right because this address is internal to the redis container (whereas the interface my web container would be interested in is the address of the redis container)?

---

**Update**:

A. `$ docker-compose ps` output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRLnS.jpg).
 B. Also note [this](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/431) issue. More specifically that

> redis cluster doesnt support docker yet (unless you do host networking) - >advertised ip address would be different from the one they can talk through

Comment: This question has now morphed outside of the scope of what I personally feel is a good SO question (see the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more details on how to ask questions, but most importantly, it should be _a_ question, rather than a list of changing questions).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I didn't get to read through the help yet, but I changed my updates that were in a form of a question to a statement. The main idea wasn't so much to ask the question, but to provide more details to the reader to help troubleshoot. Those two extra pieces of information would be helpful right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the line

```
host: '0.0.0.0'
```

from your connect.js. You need to make connections to other containers by their DNS name (redis) which will work as long as you spin them up in the same docker network. This is the default behavior of docker-compose with a version 2 yml file.

Containers may start with different IP's. I'd recommend against trying to hardcode the IP of a container into any config files since by design the target container may come and go.

---

From the issue you've referenced, it appears what you are trying to do isn't supported by the upstream authors. I'm not sure how that coordinates with your initial findings that redis-cli worked. My answer was based on the assumption of a working redis environment. To respond to some other confusion:

- 0.0.0.0 is a listening IP that indicates all interfaces should be listened to. You do not connect *to* 0.0.0.0 from the client, only listen to this address as the server.
- The empty IP address you saw is a result of reorganizing some json output, all IP's are now listed only with their specific network and there's no default IP listed at the top level anymore.

Comment: Oops I didn't comment out the config there properly and accidentally left two `host` lines there but you get the idea. Unfortunately, I still seem to have the same error outputs using `host: redis`. So by DNS name you mean the same name I refer to under `depends_on` in the Dockerfile right?

Comment: DNS will be the name of the service, in your case "redis", which is also the value that `depends_on` points to. The DNS based discovery will work from container to container that are on the same network inside of docker.

Comment: Yours comments made me look into how I can check from a container whether it can find another container within the same network. This made me update my question at the bottom with items 8 and 9. Before my update, it seems like running with `host: 'redis'` would make things work under docker-compose right (that everything else looks okay)? Do my last two updates trigger any new ideas for a possible solution?

Comment: Your current update shows the line I recommended to remove as the only uncommented line. It doesn't appear that you've tried the above suggestion.

Comment: During my test run, I did remove the `host: '0.0.0.0'` line and left the `host: 'redis'` line active as I mentioned in the comments above (with seemingly the same results at a glance). I didn't want to update my original question for this because all my logs were actually for the `host: '0.0.0.0'` case and just in case there's some minor difference I didn't want to invalidate my logs that could then potentially throw off readers. However, now it seems like not updating this has more of a negative consequence so I will update it to your suggestion. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I marked your answer as the solution because it is a combination of that, and that I wasn't rebuilding the docker images and using the updated containers on the changes to my `connect.js` file.